# How to calculate two-way mixed ICC?

Tags: r, reliability, intraclass-correlation, software

I want to calculate ICC for ***two-way mixed model, single rater, and either for consistency and absolute agreement***. I found two packages for calculating ICC (intra-class correlation coefficient), that is, "irr" and "psych". However, from their argument description, **I cannot sure that whether they are suitable for the use.** I'll describe my concerns as following.

> If they are indeed not suitable, hope you can recommend package or
> provide some work example or steps for this use case.

**"irr" package: icc**

The "irr" package, it provides detailed argument for user to customize their situation, includes model, type and units, which is all parameters we need for selecting correct ICC form [[ref]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1556370716000158). However, I'm not sure whether this is a suitable package for the mixed model, that is, when judges are fixed and NOT randomly selected, since it only describe the use of "random effect" in [the document](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/irr/versions/0.84.1/topics/icc)

> model：a character string specifying if a '"oneway"' model (default) with row effects random, or a '"twoway"' model with column and row effects random should be applied.

**"psych" package: ICC**

This is rather a simpler function, what we only need to do is input our data and it'll shows kinds of report under different ICC parameters. However, though this time [it](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/2.1.6/topics/ICC) clearly tell that "ICC3" is for "fixed set of k judges" (i.e. two-way mixed model) and report both results for single and mean of k raters, I'm not sure whether the result comes from "consistency" or "absolute agreement".

Comment: Do I declare my question clearly ? If anyone need more detail, please tell me.

Comment: Rather than seek a package to calculate it for you, it may be better to do it yourself, from the variance components.

Comment: @Robert Long Hi, thank for your advice. I saw someone on cross validate use linear model to calculate ICC, but it seems wired because the formula do not looks like a linear model. Can you refer some work example for calculating ICC for me?

The formula I know is $\frac {MS_R - MS_E}{MS_R + (N_{rater}-1) MS_E }$

Comment: I don't recognise that formula. What is the formula for the mixed model that you have fitted ?

Comment: Actually, this is the only paper I have read about ICC, "A Guideline of Selecting and Reporting Intraclass Correlation Coefficients for Reliability Research". The formula comes from here. Maybe I should restate my question to "how to fit  two-way mixed model, single rater, and either for consistency and absolute agreement ? in any forms, not restricted to package"

Comment: But what is the actual formula for the mixed model that you have fitted? Something like `y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1|A) + (x1|B)`

Comment: Hm.. you means since its names is mixed model, so its a regression problem? Can you refer some material for me to figure it out? Maybe my understanding is too limit, and cannot even answer your question. I'm not from background of mathematic. I want to use this to calculate inter-rater reliability.

Comment: The ICC3k from the “psych” package always uses “consistency” (see Table 3 in Koo & Li, 2016: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcm.2016.02.012).

Answer (score 0):

From the "psych" package documentation, under the ICC section, I found this:

> *As M&W say "The importance of the random-fixed effects distinction is in its effect on the interpretation, but not calculation, of an ICC. Namely, when levels of the column factor are randomly sampled, one can generalize beyond one’s data, but not when they are fixed. In either case, however,the value of the ICC is the same," (p 37)*

So, you can use the results from the "irr" package to report absolute agreement in a two way mixed model(as the "psych" package returns consistency for the two way mixed model). You would only need to mention that the raters were not randomly sampled but were fixed.

I used both packages to check ICC on some of my data and present the results below. You will find that the icc value and 95% CI are similar for a two way model with absolute agreement based on a single rater in both packages (randomised effects for "irr" and ICC3 for "psych")

"irr" results

> Subjects = 119; Raters = 2; ICC(A,1) = 0.942

> F-Test, H0: r0 = 0 ; H1: r0 > 0
> F(118,87.8) = 35.2 , p = 5.55e-46

> 95%-Confidence Interval for ICC Population Values:
> 0.914 < ICC < 0.96

"psych" results

> Single fixed raters (ICC3): ICC value (0.94); 95% CI (0.92- 0.96)